# Interzone interaction in Internet Explorer with WebSockets

Tags: internet-explorer, websocket, internet-explorer-11

There are a big web application on Sharepoint and "third-party" application as a bundle. Bundle sends requests on the other server than the whole application. Bundle sends HTTP and websocket requests.
It works in all modern browsers and it works in Internet Explorer 11 under conditions.
But when some facts are converged websocket connection doesn't work in Internet Explorer, there is timeout error for websocket in IE console. HTTP requests work in the same time. We use node.js socket.io library for websockets btw.
So websockets stop to work in IE when all conditions are met:

1. user doesn't use proxy server
2. the address of whole application is in Trusted zone
3. the address of third party app is in Local Intranet zone

I changed settings of Local Intranet zones as settings of Trusted zone are, but it doesn't help.

Could anyone explain this behaviour of IE?
Why interzone connection by websocket is closed by timeout? Even if zone settings are the same? And how does proxy affect? It really affects, with proxy used it is no problem with websocket interzone connection.

Comment: What is the exactly error when it doesn't work in IE? Could you please provide a minimal sample which can reproduce the issue? From the last paragraph of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/connectivity-navigation/change-keep-alive-time-out), we can know that *HTTP 1.1 is enabled in IE except when you establish an HTTP connection through a proxy server*, that might be a reason for the proxy affect.

Comment: Error message is `[object Error]{description: "timeout", message: "timeout", name: "Error", Symbol()_12.5x6b1czt79: undefined, Symbol()_13.5x6b1czt79: undefined, Symbol(react.concurrent_mode)_11.5x6b1czt79: undefined,`...

Comment: It's hard to debug without a reproducible sample. I think the issue is related with HTTP 1.1 enabled when not using proxy server and the `KeepAliveTimeout` value setting in IE. Besides, IE 11 will be retired and go out of support on June 15, 2022, I suggest that you can use a modern browser instead of IE.